# size limit of a trigger statement is 32KB

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-trigger

The size limit of a trigger statement is 32KB(Oracle documentation) however I create a trigger with a insert statement that contains 68 559 characters.

Do you have some idea about the contradiction?

Below some information about the trigger size.

```
SOURCE_SIZE      : 44725
CODE_SIZE        : 45753
PARSED_SIZE      : 0
ERROR_SIZE       : 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: @RaymondNijland "Could not find annything about a max trigger limit in Oracle 12 c docs" =>  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS758

Comment: thanks @LukaszSzozda could not find it.. Geuss i read over it because i expected the note in a qoute like the other documention had.

Comment: @jmpierre please post your trigger with `...` for that single statement to avoid too long code

Comment: If your trigger code is that big then you do defently something wrong.

Comment: The trigger insert data into a table with more than 900 columns taht is the reason why it's so big

Comment: @LukaszSzozda just ABOVE of the section you linked is the statement with the limit for the trigger size...

Comment: *" a table with more than 900 columns"*  Hmmm, that is the thing you're doing wrong. Just because Oracle allows us to build a table with 1000 columns doesn't mean we should.

Comment: Triggers should have a small footprint (in my opinion). Consider creating a procedure, put that piece of code into it, and - from the trigger - call that procedure. BTW, +1 for comments written above (900 columns? That much code in a trigger?). Huh.

Comment: Yes 900 columns(normalization is not an option). My trigger is successfully compiled. I would like to understand why it works despite the size limit of a trigger statement is 32KB.

Comment: It's not possible to determine exactly how much memory will be required for a given PL/SQL program unit; unless you get `PLS-00123: program too large` you can assume your program unit is below the limit. In your case, I'd say your trigger is below the threshold. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/limits.htm#GUID-00966B4C-B9A5-47D4-94AA-54AEBCC07CE9__BABIHIJG

Comment: *"Unfortunately, you cannot estimate the number of DIANA nodes from the parsed size. Two program units with the same parsed size might require 1500 and 2000 DIANA nodes, respectively because, for example, the second unit contains more complex SQL statements."*